# How to compile Java program with .jar library

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I can't make javac recognize an external .jar file, whose classes I'm trying to extend. I have two files in the same directory: TestConsole.java and acm.jar. I'm compiling from the same directory using the following command:

`javac -classpath .:acm.jar TestConsole.java`

But it seems like javac is just ignoring acm.jar. It gives me the error:

```
TestConsole.java:1: package acm does not exist
import acm.program;
          ^
```

Of course, acm.program is a package in acm.jar. All of the classes in acm.jar are already compiled; I just want to use them in my classes, not compile them.

What am I doing wrong?

I am running this on a Mac, and the directory structure of acm.jar appears to be valid: It contains an `acm/program` directory, which has `ConsoleProgram.class`, the only class that `TestConsole` extends.

`javac -classpath ".:acm.jar" TestConsole.java` does not work, either.

Comment: you're importing acm.program... which you say is a package... not a class.   To import a class from acm.program package you have to do *'import acm.program.CLASS'*, to import a single class OR you have import all the classes in the package with _'import acm.program.*_ ;'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check list:

1. your classes in acm.jar appear as:

   acm/program/CLASSX.class

   acm/program/CLASSY.class

   when  decanted with jar tf acm.jar
2. You're importing them like:

import acm.program.CLASSX ;

or

import acm.program.* ;

Comment: Ah! the import statement was `acm.program;`! It should have been `acm.program.*;`.

Answer (score 29):

```
javac -cp <jar you want to include>;<jar you want to include> <source.java>
```

`<jar you want to include>`  if in same directory, just name of jar will do, if not, specify full or relative paths

if more than one jars, separate with `,`

replace `;` with `:` on `unix`

If possible, use some IDE like Eclipse. I used to spend a lot of time on similar things, but in industry, you will hardly ever do it in this fashion.

Comment: I don't want to __run__ anything; I can't get my source code past the compiler because it extends a class from the jar file.

Comment: He is trying to compile, this command is for running the compiled source

Comment: This also did not work. Usually, I would use Eclipse, but it's just not feasible right now. I only want to compile one thing on this machine!

Answer (score 7):

Are you running these commands on a Windows machine? On Windows, the elements of the classpath are separated by a semicolon, not a colon. So:

```
javac -classpath .;acm.jar TestConsole.java
```

Another possibility: the structure of `acm.jar` is wrong. It's not sufficient that the class files inside were compiled from files that declare `package acm.program` - the package structure must also be represented as a directory hierarchy, so `acm.jar` must contain a directory `acm`, and within that a subdirectory `program` that contains the actual class files for the classes used in `TestConsole`.

Comment: The structure appears to be correct (I unzipped it to check), and I am running this on a Mac.

Comment: @Steve-o On Unix you wouldn't use semi-colons because the path separator is a colon.

Answer (score 2):

Whoever is trying to compile and still having the problem as I struggled for hours, I tried all the answers above and still was not able to run the program due to one minor issue.

The no-brainier issue was the semi colon after every package. I am not sure about Mac or Linux but for Windows Command Prompt this was the case

`javac -cp mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar; Testing.java`

`java -cp mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar; Testing`

You might wanna follow this both cases either in compilation or while running.

Answer (score -1):

Many years behind but i struggled with this syntax, this worked for me to add all jar files plus compile with all classes in the program to the main class

My File Tree:
Store  classes  .java files
jars     .jar files
images   .PNG files

command line:

C:\Store>javac -cp "jars/*" classes/*.java classes/storeMain.java

Comment: thats supposed to be "jars/*"

Answer (score -2):

I'm just adding for folks who are still looking for the answer to the same problem after successful compilation.

While compiling use the command as suggested above by @Michael Borgwardt:

```
javac -classpath .;acm.jar TestConsole.java
```

For executing also you need to specify the class path:

```
java -classpath .;acm.jar TestConsole
```