# Create java library with Ant

Tags: java, ant, jar

I'm trying to put some classes in a jar, for use as a library.

For this test, I'm trying to have one class, `apiInterface`, and it's in the package `project.api`.

I got here thinking I was using the library wrong, as I was getting "Package project.api does not exist" at the import line, but [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6066485/2423187) implies that the output of `jar tf project.jar` should be

```
project/api/apiInterface.class
```

while I get

```
apiInterface.class
apiInterface.java
```

The java file being included is intended, but is not necessary.

The relevant part of my build.xm

```
<target name="buildAPI" depends="compile">                  
    <mkdir dir="${jar}" />                                  
    <jar destfile="${jar}/${ant.project.name}-api.jar">  
        <fileset dir="${bin}/${ant.project.name}/api"/> 
        <fileset dir="${src}/${ant.project.name}/api"/>
    </jar>                                                  
</target>
```

compile successfully compiles the java and puts the .class file in bin/project/api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jar file will contain the list of files under the directory specified in the `fileset` elements. Since you specify the directory as `${bin}/${ant.project.name}/api`, the task will simply search under this directory and include the class file in the Jar, i.e. `${bin}/${ant.project.name}/api/apiInterface.class`.

To also include the directories corresponding to the package, simply change the `dir` attribute to point to the root folder, in this case `${bin}`. Same for the source files.

```
<jar destfile="${jar}/${ant.project.name}-api.jar">  
    <fileset dir="${bin}"/> 
    <fileset dir="${src}"/>
</jar>
```

If only this package should be included (i.e. other packages should not be in the Jar), use the `includes` attribute:

```
<jar destfile="${jar}/${ant.project.name}-api.jar">  
    <fileset dir="${bin}" includes="${ant.project.name}/api/*.class" /> 
    <fileset dir="${src}" includes="${ant.project.name}/api/*.java" /> 
</jar>
```

You can check [this](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) link from the Ant manual for how to properly use this task.

Comment: How could I exclude everything in bin and src except the api directory then?

Comment: @Scuzzball Updated with an example.