# reference a class that uses a third-party library in Java

Tags: java, class, oop, import

I have a class which uses a import from third-party library

```java
import org.apache.commons.lang3.*;        
public  class test2 {
    public void printing() {
        System.out.println(StringUtils.capitalize("hello test2"));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```

I have a second class in the same directory

```java
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello test1");
        test2 t = new test2();
        t.printing();
    }
}
```

**I have tried** compiling using these commands

```
cmd> javac -cp "./lib/commons.jar" test.java
cmd> javac test.java
```

but both gives an error : *error: cannot find symbol test2 t = new test2();*

How will I be able to reference a class that uses a third-party library

**Note:** the first-class compiles separate on its own without problems.also compiles if i remove importing external jar from first class .the external jar file is in lib folder in the same directory

link for .jar I used:https://www-us.apache.org/dist//commons/lang/binaries/commons-lang3-3.9-bin.zip

Comment: `error: cannot find symbol` should also contain information about symbol it can't find. Can you include it?

Comment: edited its test2

Comment: `public static class test2{..}` can't be top level class with `static` keyword so it will not compile, causing bytecode of that class to not be found. Try to remove `static` keyword.

Comment: the proper syntax is `javac -cp <jar you want to include>;<jar you want to include> <source.java> `
example `javac -cp mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar; Testing.java`
Reference `https://stackoverflow.com/a/52155432/1673458`

Comment: can you give me the command with reference to my project my command that works for second file is cmd> javac -cp "./lib/commons.jar" test.java . this works  for compiling the first class separately . can you give me the cmd for the second class

Comment: Removing static doesn't work still same error

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem after removing `static` from class declaration. Your example may be oversimplified or we don't have all relevant detail. `error: cannot find symbol test2 t = new test2();` suggests that compiler can't locate bytecode for `test2` class. Usually in that case if it sees source code (`test2.java` file) it can compile it on the fly, but if that *additional* compilation will fail you can see above error. So for now try to see if you are able to compile successfully `test2` (with removed `static` from its declaration).

Comment: I have tried that but produces same error but one thing is that it compiles if i dont import external jar in first file . but i require importing to perform some calculation

Comment: Based on fact that you rolled back my edit which removed `static` modifier from `test2` class declaration and you claim that compiling it worked, it may suggest that `test2` is *not* top level class. In other words it is *nested* class declared within some other class like `class Foo{... public static class test2{..} ..}`? If that is the case in `test` class you should be able to refer to it via something like `Foo.test2` (assuming that `Foo` holds `test2` and is in same package as `test`) instead of only `test2`.

Comment: sorry I have removed static from op. was a mistake . managed to make javac work from the first answer. but now java cmd not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
Above is my folder structure and compiled classes.

I have slightly Change your test2.java file here is the updated code

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.*;        
public class test2 {
    public void printing() {
        System.out.println(StringUtils.capitalize("hello test2"));
    }
}
```

and here is the command 
`javac -cp "lib/common-lang3.jar" test2.java`
let me know if this doesn't work
even `javac test.java` is also working

Comment: I need to compile test not test2 . test2 compiles fine .I have also tried removing static from test2 still same error while compiling test

Comment: Ok that worked thank you. but dint understand the reason

Comment: But new problem is java test is not working now it gives error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils
        at test2.printing(test2.java:5)
        at test.main(test.java:7)

Comment: error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils at test2.printing(test2.java:5) at test.main(test.java:7)

Comment: @cpt.John Information from classpath `-cp` is not *only* needed while compiling code but is also needed while *running* it (at compilation time compiler use it to test if every method/type/etc actually exist, at runtime it needs this location to know where to find body/code of those methods). So how are you running it, what command are you using?

Comment: I just ran java test but now that you have said i have tried cmd> java -cp ".;lib/commons.jar" test and it works thank-you