# Java fitting websites forms. Compilation problem

Tags: java, windows, web, compilation

I have found many tutorials, which showed me how to connect with websites and fit some forms, but almost all of them contained small piece of code - without imports, I figured out that i need to use special library like htmlUnit or Watij, so I downloaded it, and tried to use but i couldn't. I have tried putting all jar files from downloaded zip archive to lib folder in java compile but it didnt work. I have also try to compile with
`-classpath` - but it didn't work - probably I used it in wrong way, all time i m getting .
`Main.java:5: error: package [...] does not exist.`

How can I add library to java compiler or how can I compile file with library properly.

I m using windows and jdk version: 10.0.1, also i m not using any advanced java editor like eclipse.

So in conslusion:

```
import gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement;
import gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlOption;
import gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSelect;
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://some_url");
```

I have got something like this in my code and i m trying to compile it (after putting jar files from zip(https://sourceforge.net/projects/htmlunit/) in lib folder (located in jdk folder)) with this command:

```
javac Main.java
```

and this(where zipo.zip is downloaded archive from upper link):

```
javac -classpath watij.jar Downloading.java
```

but for every import it ended in this compilation error:

```
Main.java:6: error: package gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html does not exis
```

Thanks

Comment: Ramzel, It is really hard to understand what are you working on. Please put some code examples and how you compile your code (since you wrote you don't use special IDE such as eclipse)

Comment: I have tried to precise the question, so that it will be easier to understand my problem.

Comment: Ramzel it is still hard to understand what you actually do. It would probably help if you will write it as instructions how to reproduce, for example, go to www.blabla.com and download myjar.jar, put it directory z123, etc.
Also, I would recommend using IntelliJ and create maven project which will probably sort the compilation

Answer (score 1):

I know that it was hard to understand my problem.
I managed to find a solution while trying to paraphrase the problem.
The thing, which i was doing in wrong way is exactly the same as in article below.

[How to compile Java program with .jar library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066257/how-to-compile-java-program-with-jar-library)